# Python csv writer: write a string in front of an array, all in individual columns

Tags: python, csv

Given the following data:

```
names = ['a','b','c','d']
matrix = [array[1,2,3,4],array[5,6,7,8],array[9,10,11,12],array[13,14,15,16]]
```

I am trying to print one name in front of each array on a csv file, like so:

**Desired Output:**

```
'a',1,2,3,4
'b',5,6,7,8
etc...
```

So far, I have this code:

```
with open('test.csv', 'a') as csvfile:
     writer = csv.writer(csvfile, dialect='excel')
     counter = 0
     if matrix.any():
          writer.writerow([names[counter]],[e for e in i])
          counter += 1
```

This gives me the **undesired output** of:

```
['a'],[1,2,3,4]
['b'],[5,6,7,8]
```

How can I get each item of the array in it's own column, while still having the name at the front?

Comment: your snippet is with `SyntaxError: invalid syntax`  in `writer.writerow([names[counter],[e for e in i])`. is that the most updated code?

Comment: @JossefHarush sorry, missing a bracket. Fixed

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Think of what you want each row to look like, then build that row.  In this case, you want the row to start with one element of `names` and have the elements of the corresponding element of `matrix` appended to it. Use `zip()` to combine the two sequences into one, then form each row as follows:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
import csv

names = ['a','b','c','d']
matrix = [[1,2,3,4], [5,6,7,8], [9,10,11,12], [13,14,15,16]]

with open('test.csv', 'a') as csvfile:
    writer = csv.writer(csvfile, dialect='excel')
    for name, matrix_row in zip(names, matrix):
        output_row = [name]
        output_row.extend(matrix_row)
        writer.writerow(output_row)
```

The output of this program:

```
a,1,2,3,4
b,5,6,7,8
c,9,10,11,12
d,13,14,15,16
```

Answer (score 1):

Use this

```
for name, row in zip(names, matrix):
    writer.writerow([name] + row)
```

Answer (score 0):

You could try using [`itertools.chain`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/itertools.html#itertools.chain).  Here is a bit of sample code:

```
>>> import itertools
>>> i = itertools.chain(['a'],[1,2,3,4])
>>> [a for a in i]
['a', 1, 2, 3, 4]
```

If you just passed the iterator created by chain to the `writerow` function, you should get your desired result.